# mysqld.exe huge memory usage (450 MB) immediately after start WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I'm using same WAMP version several months and never saw mysqld.exe at the top of memory usage task manager list. (It's stuck on 442 664 K).

Problem started today.

I didn't touch my.ini ever.

All I did today was changing php.ini, (adding xdebug stuff) but turn back all changes and memory usage stuck on this 442 MB.

my.ini (part of)

```
# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M


[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M
```

php.ini (part where i made changes today and parts with resources limits and memory mentions)

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


max_execution_time = 800
max_input_time = 600
max_input_vars = 2500
memory_limit = 512M

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Error handling and logging ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

report_memleaks = On


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll      
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll      
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll   
;extension=php_opcache.dll
;zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
zend_extension="C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\php_opcache.dll"
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings    ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;   

[MySQL]
mysql.cache_size = 2000

[opcache]
opcache.memory_consumption=128
;opcache.preferred_memory_model=
;opcache.protect_memory=0


; XDEBUG Extension 
 zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11.dll"
;[xdebug]
; xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
; xdebug.remote_mode=req
; xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
; xdebug.remote_port=9000
; xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.max_nesting_level=250
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 5
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 256
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 1024
```

---

EDIT:
After two days, in which I did not use MySql, mysqld.exe task use ~7MB. I don't know a cause, I leave this issue.

Comment: Changes to your php.ini file are unlikely to affect the amount of memory used by MySQL, a totally separate application

Comment: nothing else but php.ini changed today.

Comment: Are you using MYISAM or INNODB or both? Sometimes people mix both engines, without noticing it. A second engine running would for sure require additional memory.

Comment: @Markus Müller InnoDB. Over the weekend (last two days) I did not use MySql, and today the mysqld.exe task use ~7MB.I don't know a cause, I leave this issue and I thank You for a reply.

Answer (score 4):

Yes the defaults used by later versions of MySQL did get a littel memory hungry,

I have used this to reduce memory requirements without any obvious effects on speed, of either MYISAM or INNODB databases.

Edit my.ini and add this line in the `[wampmysqld]` section

```
[wampmysqld] 
# reduce mem size for MYISAM usage
table_definition_cache = 600
```

Oh and if you are using the 64bit WAMPServer there was a littel bug, make sure the `[wampmysqld]` section reads `[wampmysqld64]` as well as adding the above line, or it will have no effect.

Comment: over the weekend (last two days) I did not use MySql, and today the mysqld.exe task use ~7MB. I don't know a cause, I leave this issue and I thank You for a reply.

Comment: Using this technique   table_definition_cache = 400   my idle memory usage went from over 450MB to 100MB.   Still crazy but there you go.

Comment: Real databases need room in which to breath

Comment: For reference, here is the relevant documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_definition_cache